# $f$ differentiable except in $1$ point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Assume we have a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that  $f$ is differentiable for all non-zero $x$, $f$ is continuous at $0$ and 
$$\lim_{x \uparrow 0} f'(x) = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} f'(x) < \infty. $$ 
Is it then true that $f$ is also differentiable at $0$?

If we drop the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous, this is not true since the signums function is a simple counterexample. But what if $f$ is continuous? I don't think this is true but I can't find a counterexample...

Comment: You should also assume that left and right limits of the derivative are finite

Comment: Right otherwise this is trivial. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Hint. By the Mean Value Theorem used in the interval $[0,x]$ for all $x>0$,
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(t_x)$$
for some $t_x\in (0,x).$ 
Hence 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(t_x)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}f'(t)$$
The same can be done in $[x,0]$ fo $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

f is diferenciable at 0. Hint: Use the definition of the derivative at 0, and by continuity of f at 0 numerator converges to 0 and denominator converges to 0 then apply L'hopital's Rule.

Comment: as far is I know for lhospital you need that both the denominator and the nominator converge to 0.

Comment: Yes this is the case

Comment: i dont think so... the limit only has to be finite.

Comment: The numerator is f (x) - f (0) , that clearly converges to 0 when x ->0 , the denominator  is x - 0, that clearly converges to 0

Comment: ah yes you are right

Comment: I'm afraid this is a circular argument. If you "apply L'Hopital rule" on "f(x) - f(0)", you get f'(0) at the numerator, which is precisely what you are trying to prove the existence of.